# setFocusable not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
eT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchAutoCompleteTextView_feed);
        eT.setFocusable(false);

eT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("Cliked on edit text", "eT.onClick");
                eT.setFocusable(true);
            }
        });
```

I wrote this code expecting the focus is not on the editText because it pops onscreen keypad which i dont want. that worked fine but when i click on the editText i want it be focused so that now the keypad pops up....but this is not working, when i click on the editText it gives nothing

Comment: the second answer should be the accepted answer.. not the first one

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the better answer is:

`eT.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
eT.setFocusable(true);`

and you don't have to create 'fake' focus.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a view, above the EditText, that takes a 'fake' focus:

Something like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Stop auto focussing the EditText -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchAutoCompleteTextView_feed"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In this case, I used a LinearLayout to request the focus.
Hope this helps.

Comment: but when i setFocusable(false) of this fake EditText as the screen gets loaded it cursor automatically gets to the 1st focusable view i.e the actual EditText and pops the keypad.....it didnt work

Comment: @Archie.bpgc you don't seem to understand his answer

Comment: can you explain please where i understood it wrongly...thankyou

Comment: The LinearLayout above the EditText stops the keyboard to show up at the start of your Activity. After that, the keyboard will show up again after focussing the EditText.